# How can i get two row from 1 in duration mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, sum, duration

I have rows like:

```
id, start_date, end_date
0, 2000-01-01 20:00:00, 2000-01-01 21:00:00
1, 2000-01-01 23:00:00, 2000-01-02 04:00:00
```

And I need get reporting result like:

```
date       | time_online
2000-01-01 | 02:00:00
2000-01-02 | 04:00:00
```

My solution was wrong cos i only start_date count.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM start_date) <> EXTRACT(DAY FROM end_date) 
THEN  
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, DATE_FORMAT(start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
ELSE 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, end_date) END) time_online
FROM online
GROUP BY date
```

Result:

```
date       | time_online
2000-01-01 | 02:00:00
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: what about lapses > 24hs? they may span in more than two days (and rows?)

Comment: Yes, I think such a situation may be. But I don't want to complicate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a (virtual) reference table with a 24 hour timespan for each date in the online table.
You can use the table itself to do that:

```
SELECT
    DATE(start_date) + INTERVAL 0 HOUR ref_start,
    DATE(start_date) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR ref_end
FROM
    online
WHERE
    end_date IS NOT NULL
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT
    DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 0 HOUR ref_start,
    DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR ref_end
FROM
    online
WHERE
    end_date IS NOT NULL
```

The + INTERVAL 0 HOUR is not really neccesary, I added that for clarity, the same goes for the DISTINCT keyword.

If you put this in a subquery then you can get with a (kind of) self-join the records with overlaps, and the calculate the difference depending on the the values:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(r.ref_start) ref_date,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,
        CASE WHEN d.start_date >= r.ref_start
            THEN d.start_date
            ELSE r.ref_start
        END,
        CASE WHEN d.end_date <= r.ref_end
            THEN d.end_date
            ELSE r.ref_end
        END))) time_online
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DATE(start_date) + INTERVAL 0 HOUR ref_start,
        DATE(start_date) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR ref_end
    FROM
        online
    WHERE
        end_date IS NOT NULL
    UNION DISTINCT
    SELECT
        DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 0 HOUR ref_start,
        DATE(end_date) + INTERVAL 24 HOUR ref_end
    FROM
        online
    WHERE
        end_date IS NOT NULL
    ) r
JOIN
    online d
    ON d.end_date > r.ref_start
    AND d.start_date < r.ref_end
GROUP BY ref_date
```